# Question about the basis of the $K-$ vector space $K^m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Definitions:

*Let $A$ be a unit ring. A left $A$-module is a triple $(M, +, ·)$ such that $M$ is a set, $ + : M \times M \rightarrow M$ is an internal operation on $M$ and $·$ is what is called an external operation on $M$ with domain of operators on $A$, which simply means that $· : A \times M \rightarrow M$. Furthermore the following properties must be met:

1. $(r + s) + t = r + (s + t)$ for all $r, s, t \in M$.
2. $r + s = s + r$ for all $r, s \in M$.
3. There exists an element $0\in M$ such that $r + 0 = r$ for all $r \in M$.
4. For every $r\in M$ there exists an element $−r\in M$ such that $r + (−r) = 0$.
5. $a(r + s) = ar + as$ for all $a \in A$ and all $r, s \in M$.
6. $(a + b)r = ar + br$ for all $a, b \in A$ and all $r\in M$.
7. $a(br) = (ab)r$ for all $a, b \in A$ and all $r\in M$.
8. $1r = r$ for all $r \in M$.

*A division ring is a unit ring in which $1 \not= 0$ and where every nonzero element has an inverse for the product.

*If $D$ is a division ring, the $D$-modules are called vector spaces.

Question:

If $B$ is a basis of the $K-$ vector space $K^m$, then every element $x_i$ of $B$ (there are $m$ elements $x_i$ in $B$, since the vector space has dimension $m$) fulfills the following:

-Each element $x_i$ is an $m-$tuple

-Each element $x_i$ has value $0$ in the $m-$tuple except in position $i$ where it takes a value other than zero.

It is right?

Or perhaps there is a basis of the $K-$vector space $K^m$ that is different from the 2 conditions mentioned above.